# $H_{n-1}(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is a free abelian group

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

need help with this problem:

show that if $M$ is closed connected oriented n-manifold then $H_{n-1}(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is a free abelian group.

thanx.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? What tools do you have at your disposal, and what are some related results?\

Comment: have no idea, this problem gave terrible headaches

Comment: What do you already know? Do you know the universal coefficient theorem? Do you know that $H_n(M; R) \cong R$?

Comment: yes I know the universal coefficient theorem, but will it help. I don't see the connection!!

Answer (score 6):

$$O \to Ext(H_{n-1}(M),\mathbb{Z}) \to H^n(M) \to Hom(H_n(M),\mathbb{Z}) \to 0$$
As the latter arrow is an isomorphism when M is closed, connected and orientable, it follows that $Ext(H_{n-1}(M),\mathbb{Z})=0$.
You just need to understand why it implies your $n-1$ torsion group $T_{n-1}$ is $0$...

Comment: Hi, thanx for your help, but can you clarify which arrow you are talking about, and the SSE above have no torsion!!!!

Comment: Which arrow is an isomorphism? I think i've told you enough, check the Hatcher, or "Topology and geometry" , Bredon... What do you mean with SSE?

Comment: short exact sequence, thanx for the help.

Comment: Don't thank me. First, try to understand why under your hypothesis $H^n(M) \simeq Hom(H_n(M)\mathbb{Z})$. Then why it gives your an answer!

Answer (score 1):

By the universal coefficient theorem applied in degree $n$ to $H_n(X, R) \cong R$, any $\mathbb{Z}$-tor of $H_{n-1}(X, \mathbb{Z})$ vanishes, hence it is a flat, equivalently projective, equivalently free, $\mathbb{Z}$-module.